# Shattering objects without creating new ones in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm crating mobile unity game where a player will be hooking flying islands with a rope. I want the islands to sometimes destroy when pulled to strong by the rope.

I know that normal way of shattering objects is to destroy previous object and spawn its parts at the same place, but it won't work in my case, because I want the rope to remain hooked to one piece after shattering the object (same part of the object that it was hooked to before).

The only solution that came to my mind is to have these objects always created from separate parts, but connected with joints or script. Then they could be broken into separate pieces on some condition. I'm not sure if this solution is good or if there is better one, it would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: you'll be pleased to know the solution is very simple.  see answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I know that normal way of shattering objects is to destroy previous object and spawn its parts at the same place,"

There is no other possibility, whatsoever. That is how you do it.

Even if you *dynamically create* the new objects, you still do exactly what you say in that sentence.

> "but it won't work in my case, because I want the rope to remain hooked to one piece after shattering the object (same part of the object that it was hooked to before)."

There is no problem whatsoever.

You simply hook that new piece to the rope.  It's that simple.

Before .. one large piece "A" and connected to the rope at some point

After .. seven pieces "B" through "H".  One of them (say "F") is connected to the rope.

You're done.

> The only solution that came to my mind is to have these objects always created from separate parts, but connected with joints or script.

Yes, you can absolutely, totally do that.

Note that when you say "connected with joints or scripts".  It is **far easier** that that!

Say you have seven pieces, named "1" through "7"

Have an empty game object called "Holder"

***Just put the 7 objects "under" holder - i.e. holder is the parent.***

It's that simple - nothing to it. Go for it!

Treat "holder" as one object.  So if you want to move it or whatever, just move "holder".

If you prefer ...... let's say that small-piece "3" is the "one" which is attached to the rope.

Simply, ***make all the rest (1,2,4,5,6,7) the children of "3"***.  It will all simply move as one thing.  That's perhaps even easier for you.

Again, you're done!

---

Regarding your good question of how to "make one children of parent object stop being children and be separate object"

Simple,

```
 smallObject.transform.parent = null;
```

but more likely, you will have some "overall" object, right?  Or, the large object is attached the rope perhaps.

Quite simply, change the parent of the small object to that parent of the large object

```
Transform currentParentOfBigObject;
currentParentOfBigObject = bigObject.transform.parent;
.. create or separate the small objects ..
smallObject.transform.parent = currentParentOfBigObject;
.. perhaps get rid of the big object if relevant ..
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! "You simply hook that new piece to the rope. It's that simple." Sure, but how can I know to which piece and at what place it was hooked before? I need it to be smooth transition. To the second part of reply: Each object before shattering must interact with physics as well as each prat after shattering, so I don't know how putting them under one empty object would help. Can you explain your idea a little bit more?

Comment: I don't like it described as "my idea".  I'm explaining standard game engineering.

Comment: "Sure, but how can I know to which piece and at what place it was hooked before?" it's impossible to answer that question without understanding your game.  Click "edit", click the "photo" button, and include screen shots to explain the game.  It's difficult to understand why you wouldn't "know where it is attached"? How can it be attached if you don't know where that is?  Note that in the second approach, of course obviously it is attached to "3"; you already know that.

Comment: "Each object before shattering must interact with physics" ...... in your "pre-" setup, of course the collider, rigidbody, and so on would be on the "holder" object, on the "highest" object.  that "is" the object.  when you **change** to the "post-" setup, of course then it is different: each separate item would have it's own rigidbody (or - whatever).

Comment: Don't forget it's completely normal that you have something (say - a car) which has a rigidbody and so on - and underneath it you have "things attached" (perhaps "door" "gun" etc.).  It's that simple.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. Can you tell me how can I make one children of parent object stop being children and be separate object? This would probably solve my problem.

Comment: I tried this in my unity project and I'm not sure if i have done it correctly. When the small pieces have rigidbodies on them they still behave like separate objects and that is not what i wanted. I want them to behave like separate objects only when they are not children anymore. The way I think it could be done is to create this parentObject with rigidbody component and its children without rigidbody - it will behave like one big object. After I want to shatter big object all children are separated from parent object and rigidbody components are added to them. What do you think about this?

Comment: hi @faken don't forget to put a link here if you have a new question ok !  cheers